# Extract substring after grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, raspbian, top, cpu-usage

It's possibile extract only the second Cpu value without any word before and after?
I need only this substring from top command.
Thanks!

[image: Picture from RasbianOS Terminal]

Comment: Try to copy command output, it's clearer then printscreen. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729720/how-to-capture-the-output-of-a-top-command-in-a-file-in-linux]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ top -bn2  | awk '/^%Cpu/ && n++ {print $2}'
85.7
```

Comment: Perfect. That is exactly what i need! 
Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method:

```
┌─[root@Fedora]─[~]─[03:43 pm]
└─[$]› top -bn 2 | grep Cpu | tail -1  | awk '{print $2}'
0.6
```

Comment: This is nearly equivalent to Stéphane’s answer, only written more awkwardly...

Comment: Agreed - however, for me personally, I can remember simple awks such as print $x off the top of my head, but struggle to do so with slightly more complex awk strings (albeit Stéphane’s answer isn't all that complicated). Simply my preferred method is all :)

Comment: I confirm. Work perfectly on Raspbian and solve my problem. Thank you for help me :)